# Artisan Schedule run not running all commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-scheduler

I'm trying to get the Laravel Scheduler to run a couple of commands, however when I run `php artisan schedule:run` it will only run one of the commands in the kernal.php file.

My Kernal.php file is as follows:

```
protected $commands = [
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('a:import')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('b:import')->everyFiveMinutes();
}

/**
 * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function commands()
{
    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
```

My console.php file has the following code:

```
Artisan::command('a:import', function(a\ImportController $runner) {
    $runner->init();
});

Artisan::command('b:import', function(b\ImportController 
$runner) {
    $runner->beginImport();
});
```

and when I run php artisan schedule:run I get the following result:

```
D:\development\v2> php artisan schedule:run

 ´╗┐Running scheduled command: "C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.0\php.exe" "artisan" a:import > "NUL" 2>&1
```

Any help in identifying what I've missed or anything else I need to do would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The output might be a bit misleading but actually is valid. You set `a:import` to be running every minute and `b:import`to run every 5 minutes so when you run:

php artisan schedule:run

you will see that `a:import` command was run 5 times often than `b:import`

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup a cron, of course it wont run...

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the schedule command in the crontab?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your custom commands inside the ***$commands*** array:

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\A::class,
    Commands\B::class
];
```